# How to make a vector based on the conditions of an inputted matrix

Tags: python, matrix, vector, linear-algebra

I am trying to make a vector based on the conditions of a matrix that already exists. Essentially, I am trying to find if the sum of a row is = to 0 and if it is I want to make a new vector where that row is now 1. And if the row is = to 1 I want that new vector to have that row as 0. (This vector has only 1, row and 1 column). So far I have started to make a new vector with all 0s. Then I created an if statement, but I was not sure how to reference that the row has to match with the matrix row that was tested. I made the if statemet but i am not sure it is working properly

Here is my code:

a_mat=torch.zeros(n,1)

```
            if torch.sum(self.P, dim= 0) == 0:
                a_mat[i]= 1
                if torch.sum(self.P, dim= 0) == 1:
                    a_mat[i]= 0
```

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Also, it will be hard to assist you without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).